# Remove ssh keys in github from command line

Tags: github

I'm creating a script in **bash** to install and configure all my workspace. How do I remove my ssh keys in github from command line?

I already search about and found this command, but this is specifically for deploy and not remove.

```
curl -u 'user:password' --data '{"title":"My SSH","key":"'"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"'"}' https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

The code above works perfectly but how do I **remove** (if exists) instead of **deploy**?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's now about using a web application as it's defined on [help/on-topic]. It might be on topic in [so].